# Unable to install qt4-designer under ubuntu 12.10

Tags: apt, dependencies

I failed to install qt4-designer under ubuntu 12.10 because I got this error message:

```
qt4-designer:
  Depends: libqt4-designer (=4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
  Depends: libqt4-network (=4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
  Depends: libqt4-xml (=4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
  Depends: libqtcore4 (=4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
  Depends: libqtgui4 (=4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4 is to be installed
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have you added some Qt related PPA's, and have installed newer Qt libraries which lead to dependency conflict.

The easiest way would be to uninstall `4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu4~quantal1~test4` Qt packages, remove 3rd party Qt PPA's, and try again.